# ESP8266 (D1 mini) fails to upload sketches

Tags: esp8266, uploading

My Setup: 3.3v LiFePo battery attached to G and 3.3 pins. Serial-USB connected.

Result: During the following code the blue on-board LED blinked rapidly for a few seconds then went off. I unplugged it to see if it was programmed but the Blink Sketch didn't run. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sketch uses 222,205 bytes (21%) of program storage space. Maximum is 1,044,464 bytes.
Global variables use 31,572 bytes (38%) of dynamic memory, leaving 50,348 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 81,920 bytes.
C:\Users\jhoxie\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\tools\esptool\0.4.9/esptool.exe -vv -cd nodemcu -cb 115200 -cp COM3 -ca 0x00000 -cf C:\Users\jhoxie\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_351972/Blink.ino.bin 
**(Everything below this line was highlighted in red)**
esptool v0.4.9 - (c) 2014 Ch. Klippel <ck@atelier-klippel.de>
    setting board to nodemcu
    setting baudrate from 115200 to 115200
    setting port from COM1 to COM3
    setting address from 0x00000000 to 0x00000000
    espcomm_upload_file
    espcomm_upload_mem
    setting serial port timeouts to 1000 ms
opening bootloader
resetting board
trying to connect
    flush start
    setting serial port timeouts to 1 ms
    setting serial port timeouts to 1000 ms
    flush complete
    espcomm_send_command: sending command header
    espcomm_send_command: sending command payload
    read 0, requested 1
trying to connect
    flush start
    setting serial port timeouts to 1 ms
    setting serial port timeouts to 1000 ms
    flush complete
    espcomm_send_command: sending command header
    espcomm_send_command: sending command payload
    espcomm_send_command: receiving 2 bytes of data
    espcomm_send_command: receiving 2 bytes of data
    espcomm_send_command: receiving 2 bytes of data
    espcomm_send_command: receiving 2 bytes of data
    espcomm_send_command: receiving 2 bytes of data
    espcomm_send_command: receiving 2 bytes of data
    espcomm_send_command: receiving 2 bytes of data
    espcomm_send_command: receiving 2 bytes of data
Uploading 226352 bytes from C:\Users\jhoxie\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_351972/Blink.ino.bin to flash at 0x00000000
    erasing flash
    size: 037430 address: 000000
    first_sector_index: 0
    total_sector_count: 56
    head_sector_count: 16
    adjusted_sector_count: 40
    erase_size: 028000
    espcomm_send_command: sending command header
    espcomm_send_command: sending command payload
    setting serial port timeouts to 15000 ms
    setting serial port timeouts to 1000 ms
    espcomm_send_command: receiving 2 bytes of data
    writing flash
................................................................................ [ 36% ]
................................................................................ [ 72% ]
..............................................................                   [ 100% ]
starting app without reboot
    espcomm_send_command: sending command header
    espcomm_send_command: sending command payload
    espcomm_send_command: receiving 2 bytes of data
closing bootloader
    flush start
    setting serial port timeouts to 1 ms
    setting serial port timeouts to 1000 ms
    flush complete
```

Comment: The uploading seems to work. Please post your code and settings in the IDE. It's not a good idea to connect a battery to the 3.3V pin while plugged into USB.

Comment: How do you know the code isn't working?  You might want to check the code is using the correct GPIO port. You upload looks OK, the flashing blue light sounds right, so I think you might be using Arduino Blink.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your input. Especially the tip on connecting the battery while connected to usb [tttapa] I finally got it to work by changing the baud rate and messing around with the settings(i.e. board in IDE). I believe I got it to work with the "WeMos D1 R2 & Mini" board whereas I was using the generic esp8266 board.